# SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN not working

Tags: android

I am setting SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN pragmatically in Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
}
```

If is working perfect. But when i choose a image from gallery and come back to fragment then it stop working.

I tried to set *SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN* in **onActivityResult**, but no luck.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Tried this. but if also fix view for all other fragments.So i cant use it.

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN); use in OnResume() Method

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Gowthaman M. I tried, but not working.

Comment: Got no solution. Changing Fragment to Activity. :(

Comment: ok then go head.